# What should the results of my chocolate soufflé be like?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate, souffle

Should chocolate soufflés in their entirety have the same texture and solidity as its somewhat firm outer shell through out its body(excuse my redundancy)?

I made soufflés for my girlfriend and I and she noted there were creamy parts and suggested that they might be raw.

I bake them at 390 degrees for 14 minutes using 7oz of chocolate melted with 6 large egg yolks, and 5 tbs of butter and a pinch of salt.

I wanna make them for us again for valentines day and was wondering if I should change up the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chocolate souffle should be warm and gooey in the middle, if it is solid throughout it has been cooked too long.  It sounds like you have it right, I wouldn't change it. If you want to prove it to her do a google image search on chocolate souffle, you'll see what the result should look like.

Comment: That said though, if she didn't care for those gooey parts, there's nothing to stop you from intentionally cooking them longer. They're your souffles, and your girlfriend to deal with if she doesn't like the result. :)

Comment: Just my opinion but you're better off making something else entirely than overcooking chocolate souffles as they get very dry. There are many other chocolate desserts to make.

Comment: @logophobe: Better simply give her a box of chocolates then. Quicker, less messy, and always a perfect end result unless the manufacturer screwed up :)

Comment: Even better yet, make a Grand Marnier souffle with chocolate sauce! :D